Prove $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}+1}{2k+1}$
Prove $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}+1}{2k+1}$
So the solution that i have:
$\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) =\ln(1+x)-ln(1-x) \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k}\cdot x^k -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k}\cdot (-x)^k \\
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k}-\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k}\cdot (-x)^k\\
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k}(2x^k) 
= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}+1}{2k+1}$
I didn't unterstand if we should take at the very end only k odd, but if we do for me the answer would be:
$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2\cdot x^{2k}+1}{2k+1}$

Please double check each of your equalities.

Your penultimate step is wrong, if $k$ is odd then $x^k$ and $(-x)^k$ cancel out, if $k$ is even they add up to $2x^k$. If you take this into account, it all adds up.

thank you, I see I have a mistake as well it must be k+1 at first
